# Question about relative permittivity

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I have read in my physics book that:

$\epsilon\gt1 $  (for *all* substances)

where $\epsilon $ is [Relative permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_permittivity)

Why is it that $\epsilon$ is never less than $1$?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/411248/255383 Helpful?

Comment: Thanks! I checked out that article.